# RunTime Error 1004. Sort method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have written a VBA macro which will sort rows based on user inputs. So if an user inputs 1, then the sorting will happen based on a certain condition, if 2 then an another condition and so on. However when I run the code I get the error "Run Time error 1004: Sort method of Range class failed". Can any of the VBA experts help how I can overcome this error. Below is the entire code block :

```
Public Sub Sortlist()

Dim userinput As String
Dim tryagain As Integer

userinput = InputBox("1 = Sort By Division,2 = Sort by Category, 3 = Sort by Total sales")
If userinput = "1" Then
DivisionSort
ElseIf userinput = "2" Then
CategorySort
ElseIf userinput = "3" Then
TotalSort
Else
tryagain = MsgBox("Incorrect Value.Try again?", vbYesNo)
If tryagain = 6 Then
Sortlist
End If
End If

End Sub
------------------------------------
Sub DivisionSort()
'
' Sort List by Division Ascending
'

'
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
----------------------------------------------
Sub CategorySort()
'
' Sort List by Category Ascending
'

'
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
--------------------------------
Sub TotalSort()
'
' Sort List by Total Sales Ascending
'

'
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("F4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

### CurrentRegion Saves the Day

Your code was failing when your `Selection` was out of range. So I created a `Sub` with one argument called `SortRange` which uses `CurrentRegion` to always 'point' to the range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Sortlist()

    Dim userinput As String
    Dim tryagain As Integer

    userinput = InputBox("1 = Sort By Division,2 = Sort by Category, 3 = Sort by Total sales")

    If userinput = "1" Then
        DivisionSort
    ElseIf userinput = "2" Then
        CategorySort
    ElseIf userinput = "3" Then
        TotalSort
    Else
        tryagain = MsgBox("Incorrect Value.Try again?", vbYesNo)
        If tryagain = 6 Then
            Sortlist
        End If
    End If

End Sub
'------------------------------------
Sub SortRange(rng As Range)
        rng.CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=rng, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End Sub
'------------------------------------
Sub DivisionSort()
'
' Sort List by Division Ascending
'
    SortRange Range("A4")

End Sub
'----------------------------------------------
Sub CategorySort()
'
' Sort List by Category Ascending
'
    SortRange Range("B4")

End Sub
'--------------------------------
Sub TotalSort()
'
' Sort List by Total Sales Ascending
'
    SortRange Range("F4")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, the code that you have given works like a charm and works perfectly fine.Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when doing an online Excel VBA course. Likely the same course. The error was in the course supplied spreadsheet. I managed to troubleshoot the problem and it was relating to this issue found on the web.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/block-if-without-end-if?

So a simpler fix but then my PC rebooted and I lost the macro that I edited and got to work.

I tried the VBasic2008 "Fix" and that works perfectly fine as well.

Just my comments on what I went thru, not trying to persuade or dissuade otherwise.

Barry